# Set initial route conditionally in react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm building a mobile app in React Native of which auth process is like Whatsapp.I want to set the `initialRoute` to 'Signup' if there is no token in `AsyncStorage` and `dashboard` if token is present.I tried this with the following code, but it always points me to `dashboard` even though there is no token in `AsyncStorage`.

**Drawer**

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import Signup from '../screens/SignupScreen'
import CustomDrawer from './CustomDrawer'

const DrawNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard: { screen: Home },
  Signup: { screen: Signup},
  },{
  initialRouteName: AsyncStorage.getItem('token') ? 'Dashboard' : 'Signup',
contentComponent: CustomDrawer,
drawerOpenRoute: 'drawerOpen',
drawerCloseRoute: 'drawerClose',
drawerToggleRoute: 'drawerToggle'});

export default DrawNavigator;
```

**EDIT**

```
async function checkToken(){
  var token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
  return token ? true : false
}

initialRouteName: checkToken()  ? 'Dashboard' : 'Signup',
```

But the app stills gives access to `Dashboard` even it there is no token stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsyncStorage works asynchronously, therefore the expression that is interpreted in your condition is the resulting Promise object from the getItem function.

You could try to use  the `await` statement to block the execution until you know if there is a token. This is not reccomended because you'll be blocking the initialisation of your app.

You can also try to have a default route that will check for a token in the componentDidMount and then redirect based on the result.

Side note:
AsyncStorage imported from `"react-native"` is now deprecated and will be removed in a future release of React-Native. Consider installing `"@react-native-community/async-storage"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Asyncstorage.getItem() is an asynchronous call. So you have to use async await.

Answer (score 0):

if you directly call the async funtion then this will always return promise that means true.that's why you get the true condition always.